# does php have a function that parses exponents in strings (eg: "9.5367431640625e-05") or does it have to be done manually via regexp etc?

Tags: php, string, math, exponent

does php have a function that will convert a string (data type will be string since its parsed from an external source) like:

```
string(..) "9.5367431640625e-05"
```

and perform the exponent calculations on said string and return the calculated value?

or do i need to use regexp etc style way to do something like:

```
9.5367431640625e-05 -> 9.5367431640625^-5 = calculated value
```

if php does not have such a function, best ideas on how to accomplish this? i was just going to pattern match something like

```
/^([0-9\.\-]+)e([0-9\.\-]+)$/
```

any better ideas?

thanks!

Comment: [`floatval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a simple cast:

```
$float = (float)$string;
```

But besides checking for `0` (which might be a valid value ...) there is no way for error checking. You could also use the `floatval()` function which does the same.

But usually you won't have to do it as PHP will cast as needed. Mind that chapter of the documentation: http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: both answers are great! picked this one because of the mention of floatval. thank you wholeheartedly!

Answer (score 5):

Do a cast:

```
$float  = (float) $string;
```